# To split a result set an based on a column value(agent mail) and pass it to automation sending in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I would like to automate report for all the salesperson/agents which will present all customer & units and their GB usage (Cellular industry).

I generate a query that shows all units that were in use with their customer and sales person link to (as presented below):

[image: DataSet]

Until now if I wanted to automate report I use to sent the query to the SSRS guy in my company and he takes care of it... how can I do it know? Is there a possibility through the SSRS To split the result set and send each salesperson/agent all the relevant rows? (like below?)

[image: Results]

Please advice.

Comment: MDX or SQL Server query? If MDX, tabular or multi-dimensional, you are looking for DAX solution... If it is DAX you can use row level security using Lookup and filter... Also for MDX you can apply filter on your required user name

Comment: Hi Thanks,SQL Server query

Comment: Then you can apply filter in where clause rite? What is your query what is your issue in the query and what is your expected output scenarios?

Comment: Are you looking for solution to change based on user who is running the query from client?

Comment: I  have created a query that shows result set which includes:1.CustomerName 2.SalesPerson Email.3.Unit id.4.GB Usage). i ask if it possible via ssrs to send for each salesperson by using the salesperson email value all the rows that are relevant to him( the rows who consist his email address in the "salesperson email"/"agent Email" field

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need Data driven subscriptions.

It is a feature of enterprise version, if you have that version this link will help.

[Data Driven Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/data-driven-subscriptions)

Basic steps are:

Make your query of the report you want to send out accept a parameter that will filter the results just for that salesperson.

Then change the above to return those parameters and the email address.

Then publish the report.

Then manage the report from your browser

Select subscriptions

Select new data driven subscriptions and fill in all the fields and select a schedule.